# Why does the following instruction not jump in gdb?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, dynamic-linking

I have the following program, exitc.s:

```
[OP@localhost linking]$ cat exitc.s
    .section .text
    .globl _start

_start:
    call exit
```

Built in the following way:

```
[OP@localhost linking]$ as exitc.s -o exitc.o
[OP@localhost linking]$ ld exitc.o -o exitc -lc -I /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

When running it through `gdb`, the following occurs:

```
(gdb) disas _start
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x0000000000401020 <+0>: callq  0x401010 <exit@plt>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) break *_start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401020
(gdb) run
Starting program: /path/to/linking/exitc 

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000401020 in _start ()
(gdb) disas _start
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
=> 0x0000000000401020 <+0>: callq  0x401010 <exit@plt>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) si
0x0000000000401010 in exit@plt ()
(gdb) disas 0x401010
Dump of assembler code for function exit@plt:
=> 0x0000000000401010 <+0>: jmpq   *0x2002(%rip)        # 0x403018 <exit@got.plt>
   0x0000000000401016 <+6>: pushq  $0x0
   0x000000000040101b <+11>:    jmpq   0x401000
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) si
0x0000000000401016 in exit@plt ()
(gdb) disas 0x401010
Dump of assembler code for function exit@plt:
   0x0000000000401010 <+0>: jmpq   *0x2002(%rip)        # 0x403018 <exit@got.plt>
=> 0x0000000000401016 <+6>: pushq  $0x0
   0x000000000040101b <+11>:    jmpq   0x401000
End of assembler dump.
```

In the last step of the assembly, why does a jump not occur?

Comment: It does, but initially the target for the jump is the next instruction.

Comment: @Jester isn't the target of the jump `0x2002(%rip)`?

Comment: It's an indirect jump. The target address is fetched from memory location `0x403018`.

Comment: No, it's an *indirect jump* (note the `*` in `jmpq   *0x2002(%rip)`, consider this as the c indirection operator `*`).

Comment: Ohhh. I didn't even know that was possible. Thanks. Could one write a simple answer, so I can accept it and mark this thread as complete?

Answer (score 1):

> In the last step of the assembly, why does a jump not occur?

The JUMP *does* occur, but just happens to jump to the next instruction.

That is entirely expected, and is how lazy symbol resolution works. You can read about it e.g. [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/).